# Autohotkey, how can I expand an in-class static variable represented as a string?

Tags: autohotkey

For example, I have a script named `expand_class_static.ahk`,

```
global gvar := 1

class myclass
{
    static svar := 2
}

expand_var(varname)
{
    theval := %varname%
    
    MsgBox, % varname "=" theval
}

expand_var("gvar") ; shows gvar=1

MsgBox, % "myclass.svar is: " . myclass.svar ; OK, shows 2

expand_var("myclass.svar") ; runtime error! How to solve?
```

Running with Autohotkey 1.1.32, the final statement asserts runtime error.

[image]

Then I'd like to know, how can I get the value of `myclass.svar` if it is expressed in a string as "myclass.svar", because I hope to pass that "variable name" around as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[**Functions**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Functions.htm#intro) says:

> Since a function call is an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Expressions), any variable names in its
> parameter list should not be enclosed in percent signs. By contrast,
> literal strings should be enclosed in double quotes.

In this case

expand_var("myclass.svar")

has to be

```
expand_var(myclass.svar)
```

because myclass.svar is a variable, not a literal string.

And percent signs are not used with the [:= operator](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetExpression.htm)

```
theval := varname
```

Comment: What if I want to write a GUI that allows user to input a global var name(including in-class static var name) so to change a global var value on the fly? Then it seems I have to store `myclass.svar` as string in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes, in accordance with the above rule. Once the variables  are defined (gvar := 1 and svar := 2), the expand_var function can work without quotes.